# Unit Testing Target not recognizing static csv file

Tags: ios, xcode4, xcode4.5, sentestingkit

I am running Xcode 4.5 and I have added a new unit testing target to an existing project.

I added a csv file to the `Copy Bundle Resources` section of the target, but the target is not recognizing the file as part of the bundle. When I run the following in LLDB, I get nil result:

```
po [NSBundle mainBundle]
(id) $2 = 0x01937180 NSBundle </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/Developer/usr/bin> (loaded)

po [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType:@"csv"]
(id) $3 = 0x00000000 <nil>
```

is there an additional step to get the target to recognize the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is a read the docs type of answer.

It turns out that calling `[NSBundle mainBundle]` does not load the bundle that holds that targets files. Instead I need to get the other bundles identifier and use that bundle. After which everything worked as expected.